# Does every set have a set that is bigger?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that for every set $A$, there exist set $B$, such that $A \subset B$, where $B$ is bigger (has at least one element more) than $A$? What about infinite sets?

Comment: Consider $B=A\cup\{A\}$

Comment: Cantor showed that, for any set $A$, its power set $\mathcal P(A)$ is bigger.

Comment: Thank you. Can you write it as an regular answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @GEdgar This doesn't answer the question. In general, a set is not a subset of its power set.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 no but $A \subset A\cup P(A)$.  ANd if $P(A)\cup A$ must be at least as large as $P(A)$.

Comment: @PinkPanther if $A$ is infinite that $|A\cup \{A\}| = |A|+1 = |A|$ so $B$ is not "bigger".

Comment: @fleablood Yes, it was unclear to me if the question was asking for just a proper super set, which would be $A+1$, or with strictly bigger cardinality.

Comment: @PinkPanther  Actually on rereading you are correct.  That probably would the *OP* meant.  Is every set a proper subset of another set and your comment is correct.  Although this assumes the OP is aware that $A\in A$ is impossible.  I'm not entirely sure what the OP does and doesn't know but I suspect this is a very basic question.

Comment: "What about infinite sets?" This implies a common mistake that "finite" means "doesnt contain everything" and "infinite" means "contains everything". This is false. Let say your set is $\mathbb N=\{$all natural numbers$\}$; that is infinite. Lets add one more thing to it $K=\mathbb N\cup\{$my uncle fred$\}$.That's an infinite set with an element not included.  Now sets are things and you can have sets as elements of sets.  But if $A$ is a set, $A$ can not have itself as a member (That's a rule). But you you can add $A$ to the set to get a different bigger set. And that's pinkpanther's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a proper super set, you can take $B=A\cup\{A\}$.
Otherwise you can take $B=A\cup\mathcal P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Cantor's Theorem states that for every set $A$, we have $|P(A)| > A$ where $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$ (set of all subsets of $A$). For finite sets, this seems obvious, and for infinite sets, you can see the proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem). So, you can define $B$ as $B = P(A) \cup A$ in order to have $A \subset B$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for every set the power set is stronger than the set itself.

Thus $A\cup P(A)$ is stronger  than $A$ and it contains the original set as well.

You know that the power set $P(A) $is the set of all subsets of $A$